# Get posts from category from custom query

Tags: posts, categories, archives, blog

Hello I have the following custom wordpress query. This displays all the blog posts just fine.

```
<?php $mymain_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => '10' ) ); while($mymain_query->have_posts()) : $mymain_query->the_post(); ?>

    //shortened code below
    <div class="blog-post">
        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
        <p><?php the_content(): ?></p>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

But I when I plug this into `archive.php` it is still calling all blog posts instead of the ones in that category.

Can anyone suggest how to edit my code to only show the blog posts in that specific category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my solution

```
<?php 
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
    $mymain_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $category_id,'posts_per_page' => '10' ) ); while($mymain_query->have_posts()) : $mymain_query->the_post(); ?>

    //shortened code below
    <div class="blog-post">
        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
        <p><?php the_content(): ?></p>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new query instead of using the main query already created by WordPress?

Comment: its for a custom layout